# How do I find a list of customers that have not placed an order in the past 1 year?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I'm having trouble figuring out how to write this query:

We have a `sales` table but the sales table only represents customers that have purchased.

We have a `customers` table that represents all of the customers that we have.

I have tried:

```
select 
    c.customer_id
from 
    customers c
left join 
    orders o 
    on c.customer_id=o.customer_id
    and c.created_at >= now()-interval '1 year'
group by
    c.customer_id
having 
    count(distinct o.order_id)=0
```

But for a table with many millions of rows, it is very slow even with index.

I'm assuming it's because of the left join.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.customer_id
    FROM customers AS c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM orders
                      WHERE customer_id = c.customer_id
                        AND sale_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.customer_id
    FROM customers AS c
    WHERE  c.customer_id not in ( SELECT customer_id FROM orders
                      sale_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 year)
```

You can make faster if you index sale date and customer_id in orders table